# Learning to Search in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a search form in my rails application. I've looked up various solutions but they make little sense to me.

I'm getting the following error when I run a search through a form in my rails app. Right now my concern (other than the error) is my instance variable @computers in my index action. I'm pretty sure it's not 'the rails way' to get a search done properly and would love some advice.

**Error**

```
undefined method `%' for #<Array:0x5780460>
```

**Parameters after Search**

```
http://localhost:3000/computers?utf8=%E2%9C%93&direction=&sort=&search=bob
```

**Search Form**

```
<%= form_tag computers_path, method: "get" do %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag :direction, params[:direction] %>  
        <%= hidden_field_tag :sort, params[:sort] %>
        <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
        <%= submit_tag "Go", name: nil, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

**Call to Method**

```
def index
    @computers = Computer.where(school_id: current_user.school_id).search(params[:search]).category(params[:category]).order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
end
```

**Method**

```
  def Computer.search(search)
    if search
      search = search.downcase
      params = []
      values = {}

      column_names.each do |c|
        params << "#{c} LIKE #{c.to_sym}"
        values[c.to_sym] = search
      end

      params.join (' OR ')
      where(params,values)
    else
      all
    end
  end
```

Comment: What line is throwing that error?

Comment: where(params,values), It's happening in isolation too in the rails console when I define that same method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the right idea, but invoking the `.join` method does not change the object on which it is called, it merely returns a string representation. You need to store the return in a variable, something like this: `paramsStr = params.join(' OR ')`. Then simply pass `paramsStr` to the where clause.

Ultimately, that is what is causing your `unidentified method % for Array ....` error; this version of the `where` method is expecting the first parameter to be a string. Check out [this documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#placeholder-conditions), the part about placeholder conditions.

Hope that helps.

Comment: As for the method itself, I've personally never done a search like this, however from what I can tell, I think this method is fine. I'm sure you can find ways to refactor it, but otherwise, I do not know how you would do such a method in plain SQL anyways without writing a procedure or manually writing each column.

Comment: That helps tremendously thank you. It seems obvious now that you pointed it out. Thanks!